# List of Laravel environments types

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

I want to know what environments Laravel supports by default. I know that "production" and "local" are two available, but there's no other? And if so, how does it alter the behavior of logging.

Another thing is that I believe that I declare one custom environment, it will cause any unexpected behavior?.

Thanks!

Comment: It won't cause any unexpected behaviour. It's common to have 'staging' as well and you can have more.

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: The @patricus is the one that I was looking for!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only values that mean anything to the framework are `production`, `testing`, and `local`.

When your environment is `production`, this just adds a little extra protection to some artisan commands (e.g. migrating, seeding). When in `production`, these commands must be run with the `--force` option.

When your environment is `testing`, this makes `App::runningUnitTests()` return `true`. This is used to disable verifying CSRF tokens when running phpunit tests. The default `phpunit.xml` file in Laravel sets the environment to `testing`.

When your environment is `local`, this makes `App::isLocal()` return `true`. This function is not actually used anywhere, unless you've used it yourself.

As you can see, you're free to set the environment value to whatever you want, with minimal consequences. If you don't use `production`, it is slightly easier to accidentally run a damaging artisan command you didn't want. If you don't use `testing`, you might have an issue with CSRF tokens with your phpunit feature tests. If you don't use `local`, this will only affect you if you already have custom code that depends on the `local` environment.

One other side note regarding the environment: as of Laravel 5.2.13, you can have different `.env` files for different environments. Laravel will first look for the `.env.{environment}` file, and if it doesn't exist, will then just load the default `.env` file.

So, for example, you could create a `.env.testing` file that will be used by your phpunit tests (since they use the `testing` environment), and it could live right next to your `.env` or `.env.local` file that is used when you're developing or manually testing the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can change production. Or local by changing the value of APP_DEBUGER :TRUE/FALSE
False means production. True means local.

You can add as many environment variable as u want it will not cause any problem. Environment mainly for storing credentials which is use by the application

Comment: I think this is also a good response but @patricus was more specific with my question. But also is good to know that I can add as many environment as I want!